# MSSQL - How to get a list of documents from a node that is using a space and a view?

Tags: nodes, database, files

I have a list of documents that are associated with a node of type space. The space has a page with a view and filter to list documents only related to that node.

I'm trying to query the database to get just that list of documents from the files table. [image: FilesTable]

My question is when Views are involved with spaces how can i retrieve that list from the database?

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.